# How to set dbContext with a connection string when it is also injected as a service

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I'm using EF-Core in a web-api project, and using the DI mechanism to inject the DBContext to action methods.
BUT - In addition - I would like to reach the DB using the **EF dbContext**, when the server is up, **in the startup method** - this is a non http context, meaning - the DBContext is not initiated yet - it is initiated in the **ConfigureServices** method, and it is initiate after the **stratup** method.
For further explanation, this is the Startup.cs and the rest of the relevant flow:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration {get; }
    
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        RepositoriesManager.Initiate(configuration);
        //In addition - I now would like to use it to initiate repository by using the EF Core dbContext
        //Another option is to run this methos after adding the dbContext serice - in the ConfigureServices
    }
    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Add....
        services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("myDB)));
        //Option to execute it here instead of in the Startup
        RepositoriesManager.Initiate(configuration);
    }
}
```

`RepositoriesManager` is a static class that using the configuration to get data from external API

```
public static Class RepositoriesManager
{
    static RepositoriesManager(){} //static constructor
    
    public static void Initiate(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        //to make a long story short:
        GetDataFromDBUsingEF();
    }

    //This method can be called also from action method (controller) - where the myDBContext is passed - this is not the case here
    public static GetDataFromDBUsingEF(MyDBContext myDBContext = null) 
    {
        if (myDBContext == null)
        {
            //one option - not working:
            
            var serviceCollection = new Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection();
            var sp = serviceCollection.GetService<MyDBContext>();
            
            
            
            //second option - also not working:
            myDBContext = new MyDBContext(); // This should initiate the DBContext in some scenarios 
        }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the dbContext **OnConfiguration** method:

```
protected override void OnConfiguration(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)  
{
   if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
   {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("<connection string key>"));
   }
}
```

This method should be called in every DbContext initiation using its constructor.
Right now it is not being reached when I initiate the dbContext. I assume that the reason is what the documentation claims:
"If a model is explicitly set on the options for this context (via Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseModel(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IModel)) **then this method will not be run**".

How can I get the DBContext when its not injected ?

Comment: Where exactly do you need to use the context.? It should really be configured in Startup.ConfigureServices.

Comment: @Nkosi - I need the context in the Startup method. The ConfigureServices is running afterwards, so it is not yet initiated. In the ConfigureServices  I'm using extension method: AddDbContext.

Comment: Show the code because I am still not clear about what you are referring to about `Startup` **"method"**.

Comment: @Nkosi - I added some more code

Comment: Inject the db into the `Configure` method and use it as needed. Read up on how you should be using Startup here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**: Get context in Startup constructor via `new`

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;

    var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MvcContext>()
        .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcContext"))
        .Options;

    using var context = new MvcContext(contextOptions);
    var configFromDb = context.MvcConfiguration.First();
}
```

**Option 2**: In `ConfigureServices` call `Configure` on required options and use context (it will be called when options will be actually used)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddDbContext<MvcContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcContext"));
    });

    services.AddOptions<DbConfigOptions>().Configure<IServiceProvider>((options, sp) =>
    {
        using var scope = sp.CreateScope();
        using var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MvcContext>();
        options.UseDeveloperExceptionPage = dbContext.MvcConfiguration.Single().UseDeveloperExceptionPage;
    });
}
```

**Option 3**: When `DBContext` is configured in `ConfigureServices` it can be injected in `Startup.Configure` and used there

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, MvcContext dbContext)
{
    var configFromDb = dbContext.MvcConfiguration.Single();
    
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it worked - used option 1 - most suitable for me.

Comment: @GuyE option 1 is the least "natural" - you should strive to use option 3

Comment: @Aviad P. - I would have if I could, but I need the dbContext to be used in the method which called from the Startup method ( RepositoriesManager.Initiate(configuration);). The Configure method runs after the startUp

Comment: Let me know if you want me to have a closer look and suggest a better flow @GuyE

Comment: @Aviad P. - Thanks. I'll do if necessary.